# Is "normal gg" and "call setpos('.', [0,1,1,0])" the same thing in vimscript?

Tags: vim

A vimscript (vim 8.1.511):

```
normal gg
if search('^<p>[^A-Z“<]', 'Wc') > 0
    echon "\n:: Line " . line('.') . ' ' . getline('.')
endif

normal gg
" call setpos('.', [0,1,1,0])
if search('[a-z,;]</p>$', 'Wc') > 0
    echon "\n:: Line " . line('.') . ' ' . getline('.')
endif
```

Running on this:

```
<p>Abc for</p>
<p>abc for.</p>
```

and the output is always the second `echon`, anything before that never shows.

By commenting the 2nd `normal gg` and uncommenting the `call setpos('.', [0,1,1,0])`, the script works as expected.

My understanding is that `normal gg` goes to the first non-blank char on the 1st line, in this case, the same as `call setpos('.', [0,1,1,0])`.

Even more confusing is that uncommenting both lines won't work, either.

Is my understanding wrong? I'm totally confused.

Comment: Your confusion may have affected the example given in your question, too. I don't understand what you want to search, get, and expect, neither. Hopefully my answer will shed some light on the topic, even though it doesn't cover your examples.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat, thanks for your answer. What I am trying to search is actually irrelevant in this case. I'm  just trying to set a start point for the 2nd search in the script and I don't know why the 2nd `normal gg` has no effect.  (My vim has no map for gg, and `startofline` is 1; but `call cursor(1, 1)` surely is a better idea. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

What happens with `:normal gg` depends on many things:

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the command immune to remapping and recursion. If someone has `:nmap gg :quitall!<CR>`, it could very well exit Vim.
- The cursor column is determined by the [`:help 'startofline'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27startofline%27) option.

## Alternatives

- The [`:help :[range]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3A%5Brange%5D) command (for the first line, `:1` or simply `1` in Vimscript) also observes `'startofline'`, but it does not affect the *jumplist*.
- `call setpos('.', ...`) is the generic version of `:call cursor(...)`. Both are low-level functions, are not affected by options, and do not affect the *jumplist*.

If all you want is positioning the cursor for the `search()`, this is probably the most readable and robust:

```
call cursor(1, 1)   " Move to start of buffer.
```